# Delete Button within Repeater does not exist within current context

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

===================

## UPDATE: 29/06/2017

I am trying to get the delete button within my repeater control to function as intended. The aim is to get the button to "fire" the stored procedure within my MSSQL database.

I would like to thank Win for his in-depth response although I am still struggling to resolve the issue. I accept that I was perhaps unable to articulate my question correctly in the first instance. I have therefore edited my post to show the code I have now. I am confident that I am close to cracking the issue and would sincerely appreciate any assistance.

Code within my *.*aspx page:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ 
ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM 
[Comments] WHERE ([Ad_ID] = @Ad_ID) ORDER BY [CommentCreationDateTime] ASC">
```

And further down the *.*aspx page:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" 
Visible="True" OnItemCommand="Repeater1_ItemCommand">
<HeaderTemplate></HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
<table id="displayCommentsTable" class="displayCommentsTable">
<tr class="displayCommentsTable"><td class="displayCommentsTable">
<asp:ImageButton ID="deleteCommentImageButtonReal" runat="server" 
class="rightCross" ImageUrl="images/Red-Cross-Mark-PNG.png" 
OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete this 
comment?');" Height="11" Width="11" CommandName="Delete" 
CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Comment_ID") %>' /><%# Eval("CommenterName") %> 
commented on <%# Eval("CommentCreationDateTime", "{0:d/M/yyyy <i> hh:mm:ss 
tt}") %>
</td></tr>
<tr class="displayCommentsTable"><td class="displayCommentsTable"><%# 
Eval("CommentText") %><br /></td></tr>
</ItemTemplate>
<FooterTemplate>
</table>
</FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

And finally, my code behind where the magic should be happening but isn't:

```
protected void Repeater1_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
{
DeleteCommentById(Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument))
}
}
private void DeleteCommentById(int Comment_ID)
{
SqlConnection conn;
SqlCommand deleteCommentById;

string connectionString = 
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

deleteCommentById = new SqlCommand("usp_deleteCommentById", conn);

deleteCommentById.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

deleteCommentById.Parameters.Add("@Comment_ID", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
deleteCommentById.Parameters["@Comment_ID"].Value = Comment_ID;

conn.Open();

deleteCommentById.ExecuteNonQuery();

conn.Close();
}
```

It is perhaps worth mentioning that if I "hard code" the line I am attempting to delete then it works. For example, if I used the following within my delete button:

```
CommandArgument='44'
```

then the stored procedure would fire and affect line 44 as intended.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Everything was working fine but as I had not specified to only return results that had not been soft deleted, everything was getting returned. Noob mistake, learnt something for the future!

Comment: What do you mean connection string? Connection strings are used to define how to connect to the database, not determine which results are returned.

Comment: Apologies for my bad terminology. I'm a novice developer and I'm still learning ASP. What I meant to say was, where I defined what to bring back from the database, I was bringing back everything and not omitting the (soft) deleted comments. My code was fine because it was (soft) deleting the comments, I just made a noob mistake and overlooked my obvious error.

Comment: That has nothing to do with a connection string. Please correct your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to use [ItemCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemcommand(v=vs.110).aspx) event.

[image]

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" 
     CodeBehind="RepeaterDemo.aspx.cs" Inherits="DemoWebForm.RepeaterDemo" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" OnItemCommand="Repeater1_ItemCommand" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <p>
                    <%#Eval("Name") %>
                    <asp:ImageButton CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>' runat="server"
                        ImageUrl="~/Images/Delete.png" CommandName="Delete" />
                </p>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

### Code Behind

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace DemoWebForm
{
    public partial class RepeaterDemo : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public class Comment
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }

        public static IList<Comment> Comments = new List<Comment>
        {
            new Comment {Id = 1, Name = "One"},
            new Comment {Id = 2, Name = "Two"},
            new Comment {Id = 3, Name = "Three"}
        };

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                Repeater1.DataSource = Comments;
                Repeater1.DataBind();
            }
        }

        protected void Repeater1_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
            {
                int id = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
                var comment = Comments.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);
                Comments.Remove(comment);

                Repeater1.DataSource = Comments;
                Repeater1.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your solution Win. I have updated my original question as I have had some issues.

Comment: You will need to assign ***unique id*** to ***CommandArgument***. `CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>'`.

Answer (score 0):

In what event are you trying to access the repeater button?

You will need to try to find the control inside the repeater item.
For eg:
    Button btn1 = (Button)rptItem.FindControl("btn1");